# Exponential of a complex number converges absolutely

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, intuition, exponential-function, absolute-convergence

$$\operatorname{exp}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

This converges absolutely for every $z\in \Bbb C$. What does this mean to a layman?

Comment: Can you define a layman? Is it someone with no mathematics background at all?

Comment: What would a layman need complex numbers, exponentials, and power-series for?

Comment: Hmmm. I have done heaps of math, but I don't know what converging absolutely means, especially on complex numbers

Comment: The layman is me if you want to just have a quick look at my past questions

Comment: Are you asking the definition of 'absolute convergence'?

Comment: @GitGud Just what it means visually or intuitively, maybe on $\Bbb R^2 \equiv \Bbb C$

Comment: Alright, well, think of it this way: the sum $\exp(z)$ depends on the complex number $z$, and since we are adding an infinite number of terms together, it's conceivable that $\exp(z)$ is infinite for some choices of $z$. If that were the case, mathematicians would be sad, because infinite things are not preferable. Well, it turns out that this never happens. No matter which $z$ you choose, $\exp(z)$ has a finite value (i.e. the series converges). The "absolutely" part is not that important of a distinction. And the fact that $z$ is complex also does not affect it much.

Comment: If you want to see this for yourself, choose a particular $z \in \mathbb{R}$, and start adding up the terms of the series on your calculator. You will notice that it approaches some value.

Comment: @Ducky That makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The ratio from one term to the next is $z/n$.  Eventually, $n$ is bigger than $|z|$, so the terms from that point on get smaller.  Eventually, $n>2|z|$, so the terms halve in size each step.  So the sum will converge.  That is true for any $z$.
We don't have the problem of $\frac1{1-z}=1+z+z^2+z^3+...$ which stops converging when $|z|\geq1$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense

Comment: You haven't addressed *absolute* convergence, though.

Comment: I did when the terms halved in size each step.