# For every $z\in \Bbb C$, the exponetial series converges uniformly on every bounded subset of the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, intuition, exponential-function, uniform-convergence

$$\operatorname{exp}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

This series converges uniformly on every bounded subset of the complex plane. What does this mean in simple terms?

Comment: Do you know what it means for something to converge uniformly?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147693/exponential-of-a-complex-number-converges-absolutely

Answer (score 1):

It means that if you want to compute $\exp(z)$ to a desired precision, I can tell you how many summands will suffice without knowing $z$; provided you tell me that $|z|$ does not exceed a certain threshold (that is, my answer will depend only on that threshold and the desired precision, not on the exact value of $z$).

Comment: What threshold do you refer? The maximum value? Is that the bounding you refer?